# NSString assignment issue? Error adding object to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I'm getting the following error when I run my application in XCode:

```
2011-06-05 16:28:53.957 QueryTesting[9452:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170fd0'
```

The problem highlights the second line below:

```
NSString *facebookID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1222740351"];
[propertyValues addObject:facebookID];
```

Is there a problem with facebookID initializing?

EDIT:
propertyValues is a NSMutableArray and has been initialized here:

```
NSMutableArray *propertyValues = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Comment: What is `propertyValues` and where is it defined?

Comment: The exception is telling you that `propertyValues` is an `NSString` when you're expecting an `NSMutableArray`. Either it's not being initialised properly or it's not being retained. We're going to need to see more code.

Comment: updated to reflect initialization of the NSMutableArray propertyValues

Comment: Damnit I initialized it as a string. God that's been killing me for an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

propertyValues is defined as an NSString object but should be either an NSMutableArray object or NSMutableSet object, or any other object responding to an addObject:-message.

Another possibility is mem corruption or you understood memory management wrong. In that case: read the memory management programming guide and ***enable the Clang Static Analyser***!